# How to get user response using ATD commands GSM modem in c#

Tags: c#, .net, at-command, ivr

I am trying to make IVR system GSM modem. I am done with calling on number using code below

```
SerialPort SP = new SerialPort("COM3");
SP.BaudRate = 9600;
SP.Parity = Parity.None;
SP.DataBits = 8;
SP.StopBits = StopBits.One;
SP.RtsEnable = true;
SP.DtrEnable = true;
SP.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;
SP.ReceivedBytesThreshold = 1;
SP.NewLine = Environment.NewLine;
SP.Open();
SP.WriteLine("ATDT0999182542;"+ Environment.NewLine);
```

Can query to call status using

```
string ss= SP.ReadExisting();
```

`State` of the call. Can be one of the following values:

0 - Active
1 - Held
2 - Dialling
3 - Alerting
4 - Incoming
5 - Waiting

Now my question is, How can i play voice message once call is answered, And can I get the number pressed by user (1,2,3).

Answer (score 1):

For voice message read about voice mail numbers and their working. Yes you can get the number pressed by the user.